# Text and other icons appear really small or really large on internal and external displays

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display

**Using:** HP Spectre x360 laptop 15" 3840 x 2160 Windows 10, HP 27wm monitor 27" 1920 x 1080, Visual Studio 2015, Tableau 10.2

**Note:** Forgive my lack of technical speaking. I am not fluent with computer hardware technical specifications, but I will clarify anything as much as possible if need be.

**Problem:** On my laptop alone and when projecting to the external monitor, most of the text and images in the different software applications I use look normal, but some parts show either abnormally large text/images or abnormally small text/images (see images below).

**Question:** How do I get everything to just appear normally (if it is possible)?

**What I Have Tried:** I have adjusted the display settings using Intel Graphics Control Panel to make both the laptop display and monitor display just be 1920 x 1080 resolution, but this did not work.

**Screenshots of Issue:** In the Visual Studio screenshot, the connections (circled at the bottom) appear HUGE, but the other parts of the application appear normal (circled at the top). In the Tableau screenshot, the data types (circled at the bottom) appear tiny, but the other parts of the application appear normal (circled at the top).

[image: Visual Studio]

[image: Tableau]